# C with Bison+Flex Checking File for Rules

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

This is my html.l:

```
DOC_START       "<html>"|"<HTML>"
DOC_END         "</html>"|"</HTML>"
SPACE           " "
TEXT            .
%%
%%
```

This my html.y:

```
%{
#include "lex.yy.c"
%}

%%
Doc         : DOC_START Other DOC_END
Other       : TEXT
            | SPACE
%%
```

This is my html file:

```
<HTML>
foo bar
</HTML>
```

I'm compiling first flex file, after bison file. It gives `has no rules` error.
I want to check that whether if this file a proper html file as described in `Doc` statement. And it is expected to give an error or message to `stdout`. What do we need to do?

Comment: So you don't allow `<hTmL>` tags?  Granted, only sadistic people are likely to put that sort of mixed-case tag into an HTML file, but should you allow it anyway?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what is better way to describe it? Can you help?

Comment: `DOC_START "<[hH][tT][mM][lL]>"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not followed the specification for a lex program as shown in the [manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Format.html#Format).

Although you have specified some regular expressions and given them names (in the definitions section), you have not told lex what to do when it find some (in the rules section, which you left empty). Add a rules section that returns a token, like this:

```
DOC_START       "<html>"|"<HTML>"
DOC_END         "</html>"|"</HTML>"
SPACE           " "
TEXT            .
%%
{DOC_START}     return DOC_START;
{DOC_END}       return DOC_END;
{SPACE}         return SPACE;
{TEXT}          return TEXT;
%%
```

Your bison code has not [specified the tokens that are coming from lex](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Token-Decl.html#Token-Decl), so you need to add those:

```
%{
#include "lex.yy.c"
%}
%token DOC_START DOC_END TEXT SPACE
%%
Doc         : DOC_START Other DOC_END
Other       : TEXT
            | SPACE
%%
```

However, if you do it this way the lex code is compiled before the token declarations. To fix this, put the include at the bottom of the file:

```
%token DOC_START DOC_END TEXT SPACE
%%
Doc         : DOC_START Other DOC_END
Other       : TEXT
            | SPACE
%%
#include "lex.yy.c"
```

Nearly there...

Now to output an error message, we need to provide code for the `yyerror` function. You wanted the output to go to `stdout`; we'll need the standard IO library `stdio.h` for that:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

void yyerror(const char* s);

%}
%token DOC_START DOC_END TEXT SPACE
%%
Doc         : DOC_START Other DOC_END
Other       : TEXT
            | SPACE
%%

void yyerror(const char* s)
{ 
 fprintf(stdout, "Syntax error: %s\n", s);
}

#include "lex.yy.c"
```

Now I notice that your compiler is following the C99 standard and issuing warnings on `implicit-function-declarations`. The tools flex and bison sometimes generate code that causes these warnings. These are only **warnings** and not **errors** and can be ignored. If you do not want to see them you can put the option `-ansi` on your `gcc` compile line.

You code will now run - I tested it.

If you are getting errors like **main** not defined, you have not supplied the yacc library (-ly on the gcc line), but you could just type up your own main program:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

void yyerror(const char* s);

%}
%token DOC_START DOC_END TEXT SPACE
%%
Doc         : DOC_START Other DOC_END
Other       : TEXT
            | SPACE
%%

void yyerror(const char* s)
{ 
 fprintf(stdout, "Syntax error: %s\n", s);
}

int main (void)
{
 return(yyparse());
}
#include "lex.yy.c"
```

Now you will see that it compiles and runs, but every html file will give you a syntax error. This is because your bison grammar is incorrect. You have only allowed one single space or one single character inside an html file (not a sequence of them). If you can't solve that problem you need to ask another question - or even better read your teachers class notes more carefully!

Comment: Very _informative_ and _helpful_ answer. **Thank you!**